# Configure Google Cloud Compute firewall to allow external access to DB server

Tags: neo4j, google-compute-engine, firewall

I've installed a neo4j database on a Google Cloud Compute instance and am wanting to connect to the database from my laptop.

**[1] I have neo4j running on Google Cloud**

```
● neo4j.service - Neo4j Graph Database
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/neo4j.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2017-09-30 09:33:39 UTC; 1h 3min ago
 Main PID: 2099 (java)
    Tasks: 41
   Memory: 504.5M
      CPU: 18.652s
   CGroup: /system.slice/neo4j.service
           └─2099 /usr/bin/java -cp /var/lib/neo4j/plugins:/etc/neo4j:/usr/share/neo4j/lib/*:/var/lib/neo4j/plugins/* -server -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -XX:+U
nlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+TrustFinalNonStaticFields -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Dunsupported.dbms.udc.source=debian -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 org.neo4j.server.Commu
nityEntryPoint --home-dir=/var/lib/neo4j --config-dir=/etc/neo4j
Sep 30 09:33:40 neo4j-graphdb-server neo4j[2099]:   certificates: /var/lib/neo4j/certificates
Sep 30 09:33:40 neo4j-graphdb-server neo4j[2099]:   run:          /var/run/neo4j
Sep 30 09:33:40 neo4j-graphdb-server neo4j[2099]: Starting Neo4j.
Sep 30 09:33:42 neo4j-graphdb-server neo4j[2099]: 2017-09-30 09:33:42.948+0000 INFO  ======== Neo4j 3.2.5 ========
Sep 30 09:33:42 neo4j-graphdb-server neo4j[2099]: 2017-09-30 09:33:42.988+0000 INFO  Starting...
Sep 30 09:33:44 neo4j-graphdb-server neo4j[2099]: 2017-09-30 09:33:44.308+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on 127.0.0.1:7687.
Sep 30 09:33:47 neo4j-graphdb-server neo4j[2099]: 2017-09-30 09:33:47.043+0000 INFO  Started.
Sep 30 09:33:48 neo4j-graphdb-server neo4j[2099]: 2017-09-30 09:33:48.160+0000 INFO  Remote interface available at http://localhost:7474/
Sep 30 09:39:17 neo4j-graphdb-server neo4j[2099]: 2017-09-30 09:39:17.918+0000 WARN  badMessage: 400 No URI for HttpChannelOverHttp@27d4a9b{r=0,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=-}
Sep 30 09:46:18 neo4j-graphdb-server neo4j[2099]: 2017-09-30 09:46:18.374+0000 WARN  badMessage: 400 for HttpChannelOverHttp@6cbed0ca{r=0,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=-}
```

**[2] I've created a firewall rule on Google Cloud to allow external access to the DB server**

*The network tag of "google-db-server" has been added to the Google Cloud Compute server.*

My expectation is that the rule below will allow any external machine to connect to port 7474 on the Google Cloud Compute instance

```
user@machine:~/home$ gcloud compute firewall-rules create custom-allow-neo4j --action ALLOW --rules tcp:7474 --description "Enable access to the neo4j database" --direction IN --target-tags google-db-server

user@machine:~/home$ gcloud compute firewall-rules list --format json
[
  {
    "allowed": [
      {
        "IPProtocol": "tcp",
        "ports": [
          "7474"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "creationTimestamp": "2017-09-30T00:25:51.220-07:00",
    "description": "Enable access to the neo4j database",
    "direction": "INGRESS",
    "id": "5767618134171383824",
    "kind": "compute#firewall",
    "name": "custom-allow-neo4j",
    "network": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/graphdb-experiment/global/networks/default",
    "priority": 1000,
    "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/graphdb-experiment/global/firewalls/custom-allow-neo4j",
    "sourceRanges": [
      "0.0.0.0/0"
    ],
    "targetTags": [
      "google-db-server"
    ]
  },
```

**[3] Running nmap from the Google Cloud server instance shows that port 7474 is available locally, and I can telnet to that port locally**

```
google_user@google-db-server:~$ nmap -p 22,80,443,7474 localhost
Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-09-30 10:46 UTC
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000081s latency).
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp   open   ssh
80/tcp   open   http
443/tcp  closed https
7474/tcp open   unknown
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.03 seconds

google-user@google-db-server:~$ telnet localhost 7474
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

**[4] However I am unable to connect from my laptop and nmap shows port 7474 as unavailable**

```
user@machine:~/home$ nmap -p 22,80,443,7474 35.201.26.52

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-09-30 20:50 AEST
Nmap scan report for 52.26.201.35.bc.googleusercontent.com (35.201.26.52)
Host is up (0.28s latency).
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp   open   ssh
80/tcp   open   http
443/tcp  closed https
7474/tcp closed unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.75 seconds
```

So despite the firewall rule being created to allow any IP address to connect to the Google Cloud Compute instance on tcp:7474, I'm still unable to access this port from my laptop.

Am I missing some additional steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like neo4j is only listening on the loopback interface. This means it only accepts connections from the same machine.  You can verify this by running `sudo netstat -lntp`. If you see `127.0.0.1:7474`, it's only listening on loopback. It should be `0.0.0.0:7474`.

you can fix this in the neo4j config by setting [dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/connectors/#_listen_address) to `0.0.0.0:7474`. Your Linux distribution may also have a different place to set this configuration.